# Caching files from hive layout S3 in Polars

Tags: python, amazon-s3, hive, parquet, python-polars

Does polars offer way to cache files it downloads from a hive layout S3 bucket?

The use case is that we have a datalake containing several TB of data. For certain tasks we may need to pull a sizable chunk of that data, but there is some overlap between S3 objects used in several tasks.  It wouldn't be practical to pull the whole S3 bucket locally, but there would be a significant speed up in pulling data if we held onto 10-20GB of data locally.

Does polars have any way to offer alternative datasources so [scan_parquet](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html) (allowing us to implement a pull through cache) or does it already have any such functionality?

---

Just to clarify the reason for this question; [the documentation of `scan_parquet()` says](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html):

> This function allows the query optimizer to push down predicates and projections to the scan level, typically increasing performance and reducing memory overhead.

I can work around the problem by predicting the files that will be needed, downloading them locally, and then running `scan_parquet()` on the local files.  **The problem** with that approach is that I lose some of the implicit decision making of polars itself in deciding which files need to be downloaded.

In an ideal world, polars would offer the ability to add new (custom) data-sources which would let me create a hybrid; dynamically using local files or downloading from S3.

Comment: If you mean does it cache from one collect to another then no. Your best bet would be to first pull in the data you need for all your common tasks upfront and then work off that. Consider that to do what you're suggesting efficiently would require it to know, at a minimum, the time cost of local io vs network io.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor no I don't agree that it would need that. A trivial space limited cache which discards oldest *(earliest last-access time)* first. This wouldn't need to care about costs since local NVME store is *always* faster than S3 HTTP request. I can implement it myself, but only if Polars supports creating custom sources